# Help with Power series discussion

Tags: taylor-expansion

How do I work out this problem? 
The initial condition is $$2u''(t)+2e^{-0.1t}\cdot u'(t)+4e^{-0.2t}\cdot u(t)=0, u(0)=1,  u'(0)=0$$

[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8loZ.jpg)

This is what I got after doing some substitution for $u(t),u'(t), u''(t)$ and $e^{\text^}$ using Maclaurin Series.
I am supposed to find the first 4 nonzero solutions in the series at about $t=0$

This one of the comments our professor gave us but sure how to apply it to get the solution from my equation.

[Professo Comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8Qub.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can find higher derivatives at $t=0$ by differentiating the differential equation.

Differentiate your differential equation one more time and plug in the known values at $t=0$ to find the $f'''(0)$

Differentiate again and plug in the known derivatives to find $f^{(4)}(0)$ and so forth.

Once you have your derivatives at $t=0$ you can find your series.